# How to configure lsp-cmake lsp server in vanilla emacs

Tags: init-file, lsp-mode, lsp

I want to setup [lsp-cmake](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-cmake/) lsp server in my vanilla emacs.

I just installed lsp server using `pip install cmake-language-server`.

I don't know how to configure in my emacs init.el to use the lsp server. The couldn't find any documentation as well for emacs.

How can I configure lsp-cmake in my init file for emacs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like the following.

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t)

(use-package cmake-mode
  :ensure t
  :mode ("CMakeLists\\.txt\\'" "\\.cmake\\'")
  :hook (cmake-mode . lsp-deferred))

(use-package cmake-font-lock
  :ensure t
  :after cmake-mode
  :config (cmake-font-lock-activate))
```

The `lsp-mode` package provides additional features like integration with `which-key`, showing `diagnostics` and `breadcrumbs`, which you may want to explore if they are important for you with `cmake-mode`.